# What should I do about a 110v adapter that I plugged into a 220v socket?

Tags: ac-adapter

I plugged a new 110v Belkin router into a 220v socket. It had an adapter so I'm assuming the router is fine and the adapter just blew its fuse. I live in the Philippines, where there isn't any service centre. Now, I see two options: Repair the adapter, or get a universal adapter. I've tried finding someone to repair it but no luck. As for getting a universal adapter, I cant't find one that has an output of 12v and 1.5A.

I'm open to any suggestions. I also acknowledge that I'm a software guy and don't know much about hardware so I also need to know if my assumption my adapter being the only thing broken is correct.

Comment: Please don't forget to go back and mark useful answers to your questions as accepted.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I already addressed the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's almost nothing you can do. Most adapters used today are sealed and cannot be easily opened without damaging them. Also, there's a good chance that the adapter doesn't have a fuse and that the voltage regulator itself died. There's also a chance that other components could have been damaged, like capacitors, diodes and so on.

If you can't find an adapter with provided capabilities, then go for one that can supply higher current. 1.5 A is the minimum current you should look for. If you can find better, go for it.

Also, be sure to check for more modern adapters. Switch mode power supplies which can work form 100 V to 250 V and from 47 Hz to 63 Hz aren't very rare, so you may be able to get one.

As for repairing the adapter yourself, I doubt that you could easily do it. You'd need to find an electronic component store and get the spare parts, if they do have them, and then fix it, which can turn out to be extremely difficult. Plus, there's the needed equipment. Electronic component stores usually sell power supplies which provide standard voltages such as 12 V, so that could be a good direction to look in.

The last option is to order an adapter from some web store such as digikey, mouser, farnell or someone who sells consumer electronics. It seem that [Farnell](http://ph.element14.com/) has a store in Philippines.

As for router damage, it's difficult to say if it is damaged or not. Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do until you power it on or open it. If you do open it, you could look for standard burn marks, visible damage, do continuity tests, if you have a multimeter and so on, but even if you do all that, there's no guarantee that the router will work once you connect the new power supply.

Comment: thanks alot. I went to ACE hardware (a hardware store in the Philippines in case your not from here) and got a chinese adapter with switchable power modes. My router is fine and everything is working great. I'm glad to know I really couldn't fix it without wasting lots resources and time.